# middleware redirecionando para tela de login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, framework

boa tarde a todos! tenho a rota abaixo:

```
Route::get('produtos', 'ProdutosControlador@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

bom acontece que usando o postman eu estou tentando acessar e por qualquer motivo o laravel redirecionam automaticamente para a página de login...
eu quero ter acesso a mensagem de erro , como eu faço para ver o que deu de errado e como faço para parar esse redirecionamento???
Sem mais,obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: Você está enviando as informações de acesso pelo postman?

Comment: sim...envio pelo postman e restlet, e ambos redirecionam...

Comment: E quais os dados que você envia?

Comment: mando o token gerado, e a url que eu quero acessar...

Comment: está adicionando o header `content-type: application/json` ?

Answer (score 0):

Isso também acontece comigo em algumas rotas testando com Postman. Consigo resolver adicionando o header `Accept:application/json` então sempre que estou testando apis no Postman eu uso este header.